# How can I save space when storing boolean data in c#

Tags: c#, azure

I need to store boolean data in Windows Azure. I want to make the space these take up as small as possible. What I have is about fifteen fields with values that are true of false.

```
field_1 = true;
field_2 = true;
field_a = false;
field_xx = true;
```

I had an idea that I could take these, convert the true and false to 1s and 0s and then store as a string something like 1101. Is there a simple way that I could do this coding and then uncode when getting the data out? Note that the field names are all different and so I can't use a fancy for loop to go through field names.

Comment: Well, I don't know how many bytes a boolean occupies, but surely a single character would take at least two bytes to store, so I see no real gain in this choice. Instead you could have stored them as single bits in an integer

Comment: [Usually: No.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) (edited)

Comment: To those of you who think this is premature optimization, see the comments on @Blindy's answer below. In short, it's too big to fit on the OP's Azure account in its original form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int bits = (field_1 ? 1 : 0) | (field_2 ? 2 : 0) | (field_3 ? 4 : 0) | (field_4 ? 8 : 0) | ...

field_1 = (bits & 1) != 0;
field_2 = (bits & 2) != 0;
field_3 = (bits & 4) != 0;
field_4 = (bits & 8) != 0;
...
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can even imagine how skeptical I am that this will help in any way, shape or form. 15 booleans is literally nothing.

Now, if you insist on going down this path, the best way would be to store them as a single `int` and use `&` to read them out and `|` to write them back in.

Comment: I would imagine that, since the OP is talking about fields, there are multiple tuples of 15 booleans each.

Comment: 15 booleans times 5 for field name = 75

Comment: 15 booleans times 10 to store the words false.

Comment: @Johnathan, well if you're really working on an embedded system (what else would have 1MB max storage?), you should put in the time to learn bit operations and store your 15 booleans in an integer like I mentioned before.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a BitArray to pack the booleans into an `int`:

```
BitArray b = new BitArray(new bool[] { field_1, field_2, ..., field_xy });
int[] buffer = new int[1];
b.CopyTo(buffer, 0);
int data = buffer[0];
```

You can use a `byte` or `int` array. A `byte` can hold up to 8 booleans, an `int` up to 32. To hold up to 16 booleans you could use a byte array with two bytes, or a single `int`, depending on whether the overhead of an array or the unused bits in the `int` take up more space. You could also use the `BitConverter` class to convert a two byte array into a `short`.

To get the booleans back you create a BitArray from an array of `byte` or `int`:

```
BitArray b = new BitArray(new int[] { data });
field_1 = b[0];
field_2 = b[1];
...
field_xy = b[14];
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider an enumeration with the [Flags] attribute

```
[Flags]
public enum Values
{
  Field1 = 1,
  Field2 = 2,
  Field3 = 4,
  Field4 = 8
}    
Values obj = Field1 | Field2;
obj.HasValue(Field1); //true
obj.HasValue(Field3); //false
int storage = (int)obj;// 3
```

Comment: How do you put it on Azure?  Cast it to an `int`?

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother. You're using boolean values, which are already about as small (for an individual value) as you can get (1 byte I believe). And the small amount of space that you *might* be able to save would not be worth the added complexity of your code, plus the time it would take you to develop it.

---

A few more thoughts: think how you'd use such a construct. Currently, if you look at `field_1` and see a value of `true`, you don't have to look further into the implementation to figure out the actual value. However, let's say you had the following string: "100101011011010" (or  an integer value of `19162`, which would be more efficient). Is `field_1` true, or is it false? It's not inherently obvious -- you need to go find the implementation. And what happens when you need to support more fields somewhere down the line? You'll save yourself a lot of heartache by sticking with what you've got.

Answer (score 1):

Storing these as characters will take either 8 or 16 bits per value.  I'd pack them into the an array of the longest unsigned integer available, using bit-shifting operations.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great post on this at:
http://blog.millermedeiros.com/2010/12/using-integers-to-store-multiple-boolean-values/

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) class, it should do exactly what you need.

Example:

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray
(
    new bool[]
    {
        false, true, false, false, true, 
        false, true, false, true, false,
        false, true, false, true, false
    }
);

short values = 0;

for( int index = 0; index < bits.Length; index++ )
{
    if( bits[ index ] )
        values |= ( short )( values | ( 1 << index ) ); 
}

Console.WriteLine( Convert.ToString( values, 2 ) );
```

You now have 15 bool variables stored in a single 16 bit field.

Comment: I'm afraid, it won't save the space.

Comment: @Optillect compared to storing them as a string or individual bool variables? I think so.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with an int and using xor http://www.dotnetperls.com/xor

I saw a project that did this about 15 years ago. But it ended up with a limitation of 32 roles in the system (it used a 32 bit number). That product does not exist today :)

So do not do it, store values in an array or seperate fields.

Comment: `roles + 32 bits == game over?` I suspect the project had other troubles.

Answer (score 0):

you could use Enum with the flags attribute. You say you have 15 fields. So you could try using something like 
[Flags]
enum Fieldvals
{
Field1, Field2, ....
}

take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx for the guidelines

Answer (score 0):

You can store your flags in an **integer value.**  Here are some helper methods to accomplish that:

```
// Sets the given bit position in the UInt32 to the specified boolean value 
public static UInt32 Set(UInt32 u, int position, bool newBitValue)
{
    UInt32 mask = (UInt32)(1 << position);

    if (newBitValue)
        return (u | mask)
    else
        return (u & ~mask);
}

// Gets a bit value from the supplied UInt32
public static bool Get(UInt32 u, int position)
{
    return ((u & (UInt32)(1 << position)) != 0);
}
```